# jQuery input value not updating with form submission

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

Before my HTML form submission, I am putting some values in my hidden input element, which is not submitted with my form, any error or something?

For ex:

Below is my form function:

```
<form id="clientForm" name="clientForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="clients.php" onClick="beforeSubmit(); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="OLD_BRANCH_FILTERS_ALL" id="OLD_BRANCH_FILTERS_ALL" value="">
</form>
```

Below is my JS function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function beforeSubmit(){

        $('#OLD_BRANCH_FILTERS_ALL').attr('value', 'xyz');

        alert(document.getElementById('OLD_BRANCH_FILTERS_ALL').value);

        document.clientForm.action = 'clients.php?saveBtn=Save';
        document.clientForm.submit();
    }

</script>
```

Now, When I check the form request `$_REQUEST` in PHP, it shows no value in element.

Any clue why its not working.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Tried using `onSubmit` instead of `onClick`?

Comment: I tried your code on my local XAMP and it is working. The submit page did show value xyz. Check that you don't have any error somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your onlick is not called in time to set the values, try it this way

```
<form id="clientForm" name="clientForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="clients.php">
    <input type="text" name="OLD_BRANCH_FILTERS_ALL" id="OLD_BRANCH_FILTERS_ALL" value="">
</form>
```

and the jquery

```
$('#clientform').submit(function() {
    beforeSubmit();
});
```

Also, if you also wanted to provide validation to the field you could use,

```
$('#clientform').submit(function(e) {
    beforeSubmit();
    if (!{VALID}) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```